# Info light button problem

Tags: iphone

I am added Info light button in UIToolbar in UIViewController Xib .....Now i want to increase the size of the button ..I am trying to increase the frame size of the button in xib.But, its dont have an editable frame size....

I want to increase the touchable area....

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to do this programmatically.
Hook up the info light button as an IBOutlet,
then in viewDidLoad you can change the frame to a larger size.
I tried it out a bit and it seems the image does not get any bigger but the touchable area does.

Answer (score 0):

Hook up the info button you created in Interface Builder with a `UIButton` created in your code.  In this case the button is called `infoButton`.

```
CGRect infoRect = CGRectMake(infoButton.frame.origin.x-25, 
                             infoButton.frame.origin.y-25,  
                             infoButton.frame.size.width+50, 
                             infoButton.frame.size.height+50);
                             [infoButton setFrame:infoRect];
```

That will increase the touchable area!